# Mariadb installed with brew not works on macos

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

For work, the development stack we use is `nginx + php + apache + mariadb`, and using mac (with m1 chip).
I set up the development environment using brew.
The installation of the services was successful and even running the `brew doctor` command I am not shown any errors.
However, I have a problem with starting mariadb, that is when I launch `brew services start mariadb` with mariadb latest, that is 10.6, I get the message of service started successfully, but when I do `brew services` under mariadb it service status is `stopped`.
I am new to mac os, I have tried to search online but everything I have tried so far has not worked.
Do you have any suggestions or advice?

- EDIT:

if i try to start service with `mysql.server start`command, i've this error:

```
Starting MariaDB
.211209 11:55:38 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Mac-mini-di-Ezio.local.err'.
211209 11:55:38 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (73339) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to work this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @bogdan hi, yes i've solved the problem...in my case i've a problem with the brew formulae.
i've removed the package, and installed via brew but i've founded the brew formulae on mariadb documentation.
It works fine without problem

Comment: Thank you. I'll follow the documentation. Cheers.